# Searching for the title of a book (/series) about a teenager and spiders

Tags: identification-request

I am searching the title of a book (and if possible, its series). I have read the books approximately 5 or 6 years ago, so I don't remember the title. The book was written for YA, and the genres were SF and I believe Romance

The story goes something like this:
Main character is on a ship or station somewhere near the poles. The ship (or station) gets attacked by something and the surviving people get rescued to somewhere.
At the new place, something is suspicious as strange things happen and the protagonist has visions of him and other people being attacked by huge spiders.

Sadly, that is all I can remember.
I hope this is enough to find the title, I have searched for some time but haven't found anything.

Comment: Titles that could potentially match include The Space Between Us by Thrity Umrigar, the Partials Series by Dan Wells, and the Sky Jumpers Series by Peggy Eddleman.

Comment: @Adzetto, thank you for the titles. I had a quick look, but sadly, none of them fit the story I remember.  One detail I remember is the series having at least 3 volumes. I'll edit the question tomorrow and do some more research

Comment: Maybe The Spiderwick Chronicles? Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: Some parts of this remind me of "Below Zero" by Dan Smith, but that doesn't form part of a series